# Is it safe to install / run Docker Desktop WSL2 and Docker within WSL2 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia-geforce, docker-for-windows

I am running Windows 10 and I have already installed Docker Desktop with WSL2 integration. I have an NVIDIA GPU in my laptop and I want to run GPU-accelerated containers using NVIDIA's Container Toolkit; however, according to the [known limitations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations) section of NVIDIA's WSL user guide, Container Toolkit does not yet support the Docker Desktop WSL2 backend. Therefore, I must install Docker-CE from within Ubuntu running on WSL2.

Is it safe to install and run both versions of Docker simultaneously, or will this cause issues?

Comment: What unsafe thing you're thinking of? WSL has many issues with the workload type that you've mentioned. I'd suggest to use a GNU/Linux distro installation.

Comment: I don't have anything in mind, but I imagine it could be an issue (e.g. maybe installing docker within WSL2 and then installing Docker Desktop WSL2 backend will cause some files to be overwritten within Ubuntu). I'm just wondering if it will cause issues and if so, what issues will it cause?

Comment: I was also planning to do this so that I could (try to) run both Windows and Linux containers simultaneously.  Unfortunately running Docker inside Linux in WSL2 does not currently work due to lack of iptables support https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/767#issuecomment-673443379

Comment: How is it going? I have a Docker desktop but without WSL2. docker is running. But now some containers e.g. Laravel 8 requires WSL2 with Docker. But according Microsoft doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 it requires to be in insiders program and it means this ---> The experimental and early prerelease software and services made available to you in the Program might not be tested. You might experience crashes, security vulnerabilities, data loss, or damage to your device. ... 

IT SOUNDS REALLY BAD. what do you thing about it?

Comment: I needed to use the GPU for a class I was taking, but eventually gave up and just used Google Colab because it was too much of a pain to setup. However, I did join the fast ring of the insider's program, and, for the most part, things are pretty stable for me. There have been a couple instances where my system crashed, but the issues were fixed quite quickly. If you join the fast ring, though, just know that you will need to reinstall Windows if you ever to leave, so maybe join one of the other insider programs instead if you are unsure.